# Replicate these AliasMatches within .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I recently purchased shared hosting for an app that previously worked well on my local server via Apache Virtual Host configuration. However, my shared hosting provider (like most) does not give customers access to the `httpd-conf` files, meaning I have to emulate the configuration within an `.htaccess` file (or multiple). This presents a problem, because `.htaccess` does not support `<VirtualHost>` configuration including the very important `AliasMatch` directive. So my question to the community is how might one replicate the following AliasMatches using `RewriteRules` or `Redirects`:

```
AliasMatch /app/(.*)\.(js|css|rdf|xml|ico|txt|gif|html|png|jpg|jpeg|json|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf)$  "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/app/$1.$2"
AliasMatch /i18n/(.*)\.json$  "/wamp/www/siteroot/app/i18n/$1.json"
AliasMatch /(.*)\.(js|css|rdf|xml|ico|txt|gif|html|png|jpg|jpeg|json|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf|csv)$      "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/adminApp/$1.$2"
AliasMatch /rest/(.*) "C:/wamp/www/siteroot/rest/$1"
AliasMatch /img/(.*)  "C:/wamp/www/siteroot/adminApp/img/$1"
AliasMatch /(.*)      "C:/wamp/www/siteroot/adminApp/index.html"
```

The filepaths will obviously be changed accordingly. It seems too obvious to just do:

```
RewriteRule {regex} {filepath} [R=301]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove the root part out, and use `L` instead of `R=301` (which will externally redirect, causing the browser to request a new URL and change what's in the location bar):

```
RewriteEngine On

# this is to prevent looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^app/(.*)\.(js|css|rdf|xml|ico|txt|gif|html|png|jpg|jpeg|json|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf)$  /app/$1.$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^i18n/(.*)\.json$  /app/i18n/$1.json [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(js|css|rdf|xml|ico|txt|gif|html|png|jpg|jpeg|json|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf|csv)$      /adminApp/$1.$2 [L]
# Doesn't look like you need this rule
RewriteRule ^rest/(.*) /rest/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)  /adminApp/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)      /adminApp/index.html [L]
```